# How can I pass VBA variant array data type through COM interop into C# method

Tags: c#, .net, vba, com, com-interop

Currently I am trying to pass a variant data type array into a c# method through the COM interop. The issue is, passing it as:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray)
```

However this doesn't seem to be working, does anyone have any tips of how I could pass this as a parameter?

Here is my full c# source:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ExpandExcel
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public class ExpandExcelStandard
    {
        #region Public Static Methods

        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray)]
        public static T[] RemoveDuplicates<T>([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray)] ref T[] arr)
        {
            // Creates a hash set based on arr
            HashSet<T> set = new HashSet<T>(arr);
            T[] resultArr = new T[set.Count];
            set.CopyTo(resultArr);
            return resultArr; // Return the resultArr
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Here is my full VBA source:

```
Sub main()
    Dim arr(1000000) As Variant

    Dim ExpandExcel As ExpandExcelStandard
    Set ExpandExcel = New ExpandExcelStandard

    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        Randomize
        arr(i) = Int((1000000 + 1) * Rnd)
    Next i

    Dim resultArr() As Variant

    resultArr = ExpandExcel.RemoveDuplicates(arr)
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to show us the full C# declaration, and the full native definition (vba, other)

Comment: I mean't this as a general question, I was making a point of saying that marshalling it as a safe array wouldn't work. I want people to give me tips on how they think they could tackle this.

Comment: It's very possible that you don't even need a specific MarshalAs. p/invoke offers lots of possibilities, it really depends on the two sides of the interop boundary. Provide code if you need help

Comment: I have edited the original question to include the source code :)

Comment: Surely the real problem is that you can call this method at all.  Neither generic nor static methods are [ComVisible].  To match the VBA code it will have to be public object[] RemoveDuplicates(ref object[] arr).  How you are going to define equality for these objects is a mystery btw.

Comment: Previously I was using object[] as a parameter, however I don't know how I can then process this object and use it in the function. I was thinking of a struct with a variable of each data type. May I also add that static methods are ComVisible as passing this method without the generic type and just as an array of strings does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use generics with COM, you can't use static functions, etc.
Here is a similar code that should work:

VB

```
Sub main()
    Dim arr(1000000) As Variant

    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        Randomize
        arr(i) = Int((1000000 + 1) * Rnd)
    Next i

    Set ExpandExcel = CreateObject("ExpandExcelStandard") // I used late binding but early is fine too
    resultArr = ExpandExcel.RemoveDuplicates(arr)
End Sub
```

C#

```
[ProgId("ExpandExcelStandard")] // because I wanted late binding, I declared a progid
[ComVisible(true)]
public class ExpandExcelStandard
{
    // .NET object (w/o any Marshal spec) is passed as an automation Variant
    public object[] RemoveDuplicates(object[] arr) => new HashSet<object>(arr).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Didn't work, gave the error, "Method or data member not found".

Comment: @user3551497 - are you sure you have copied my code 100% exactly? I've tested it.

Comment: Adding ref before object[] worked for me, thanks a lot for the help!